# Convergence region of functional series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^2+k}{x^2+k^4}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find the convergenge region of the functional series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^2+k}{x^2+k^4}$. It seems that the series converges anywhere in the region $X=(-\infty, \infty)$, but are there any ways to prove it? And how to know where the series converges absolutely? The D'Lambert's criterion has an inconclusive result. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Limit comparison?

Comment: Asking where the series converges absolutely is a bit silly, since the terms are all positive.

Comment: Also, how are we supposed to read the term corresponding to $k=0$?

Comment: It converges. For every $x$, when $k$ is big enough you can show $\frac{x^2+k}{x^2+k^4}<2\frac{k}{k^4}$ which implies it converges pointwise.